# If statement inside a case statement c seems to ignore condition and just do else

Tags: c, if-statement, cmd, case

I am using cmd to launch my program and it reads through arguments typed in cmd and the if statement doesnt seem to work it just goes to else and executes. its supposed to read if the 4th argument typed in is = (in this case) "something" then execute the code.. anyone has any idea ?

```
int main(int inputn, char* inputs) 
 { 
    switch (inputn)
       {
          case 6:
          if(input[4] == "something") 
          {
             //code
             break;
          }
             else       
          {
             //code   
             break;
          }
          .
          .
          .
          default:
             //code
             break;
          }
```

}

Comment: you need to do a `strcmp`

Comment: That's not how you compare strings in C.  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/

Comment: but its an array do i still need to do strcmp. should just the 4th entry in the array be == to something

Comment: It is an array of char* pointers.  == is comparing pointer values in your case.  So yes, you need to do a strcmp call.  Also input[4] is the 5th entry.  Arrays are zero-indexed.

Comment: Icantreaditanywaybecasueofthepoorindentation

Comment: @deathskiller did you read the helpful link before replying "but..."?

Comment: If you do `==` you are just comparing the locations where the strings are stored, not what the strings actually are.

Comment: @WeatherVane yes and now i get the error that left operand must be l -value

Comment: `main` has the wrong signature. Compiler warnings exist for good reasons. You should get at least one. And format your code properly.

Comment: i did if(strcmp(input[4],"something" = 0))

Comment: Please consult a C tutorial. You cannot assign the value `0` to a literal string pointer.

Comment: @user3528438: Huh? It compares an integer with a pointer.

Comment: @WeatherVane dude whats wrong with you im just trying to learn C..

Comment: @deathskiller, "dude", stack overflow is no tutorial site. You are supposed to do at least _some_ research on your own. And how to compare strings and the correct siganture of `main` are shown in every C book.

Comment: We have told you what's wrong. You cannot compare strings by equality. Your attempt in comment is another question, and is totally wrong.

Comment: Alright thanks for your help.

Comment: @Olaf All right, now the whole thing is UB from the very first line, nice!

Comment: @user3528438: Not really. See the standard.

Comment: thank you for the strcmd suggestion it works perfectly :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

//Try this

if(strcmp(input,"something")==0)

Comment: i did that at the start and it didnt work i had to store it in another variable and then check if the variable == 0 and then it worked but yeh thats basically it!